# Are these questions good candidates for merging?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There are two overlapping questions, each with one or more good quality and well-received answer.

1. [Are there any CubeSats that have been launched into Geostationary (GEO/GSO) or Geostationary Transfer Orbit (GTO)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22688/12102) August 2017, has [this good answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22721/12102) about *future launches* to GEO or GTO but no present satellites.
2. [Are there cubesats in GEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36514/12102) June 2019, has [this good answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36515/12102) demonstrating *no current cubesats* in GEO.

I wonder if this is a candidate for merging in order to make sure both good answers receive eyeballs? Or perhaps modifying the first (older) question to ask about *future plans*?

Right now I'd hate to close one as duplicate of the other because the answers are both good and deserve to be on non-closed questions.

Comment: Is it even possible to move an answer from one question to another?  Because that might be the ideal solution.

Comment: @DrSheldon see [What is a “merged” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158066/303080) It's something moderators can do in certain cases, whereas modifying question 1 to be past and 2 to be future is something other users can do without making work for moderators. Making work for someone else is never the "ideal" solution ;-)

Comment: @DrSheldon see also [Are there guidelines on direction for merging questions (which question to close/merge?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107846/303080)